# tuples stored in series to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a DataFrame with one of the series containing tuples like:

```
[('Available', 'Now'),
  ('Age', '27'),
  ('Language', 'English'),
  ('Nationality', 'British'),
  ('Gender', 'Male')]
```

I need to convert this into a table with first part of the tuple as the column name and second as value.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Are you going to have multiple tuples with "Available", "Age", etc ?

Comment: Example above represents data for one row, I have got multiple rows like this. Also, it if worth mentioning that columns are not entirely consistent, so that is can be some other data present, like ('Smoking', 'No')

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your list to a dictionary and make a dataframe. You'll need to provide an index since you only have one data point:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict([
    ('Available', 'Now'),
    ('Age', '27'),
    ('Language', 'English'),
    ('Nationality', 'British'),
    ('Gender', 'Male')
]), index=[0])
```

Comment: I am tryping to make like this, but it wants to know the columns at the beginning. I do not know my columns though:

df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (len(wanted_merged)):
    df.loc[len(df)]=pd.DataFrame(dict(features_list[i]), index=[0])

Comment: @DmitriyGrankin Are you able to make the dataframe as you wanted in your post? Are you describing a second problem now? I'm not clear on what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Just import as list and do `transpose`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([('Available', 'Now'),
  ('Age', '27'),
  ('Language', 'English'),
  ('Nationality', 'British'),
  ('Gender', 'Male')]).transpose()
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```

Output

```
Available   Age Language    Nationality Gender
Now         27  English     British     Male
```